# Confusion over Exponential Distribution Notation and Subsequent Consequences with MLE

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $Y_i \sim ind$. exponential$(\mu_i)$ where $\mu_i = \frac{1}{\beta x_i}$ where $\beta > 0$ and $x_i > 0$. Find $\beta$ maximizing: $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\text{pdf}_{Y_i}(y_i)$$
My confusion arrises from whether or not "exponential$(\mu_i)$" $\implies$ the p.d.f. of $f_{Y_i}(y_i)=\frac{1}{\beta x_i}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta x_i}y_i}$ or something similar to that of: $f_{Y_i}(y_i)=\frac{1}{\beta x_i}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta x_i}}$. If the former case is correct, I would think the problem would follow as provided below, but something simply seems misinterpreted when summing over $y_i$ and $x_i$ together:

We know $f_{Y_i}(y_i)=\frac{1}{\beta x_i}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta x_i}y_i}$ Therefore, by standard MLE practices, we have $$\mathscr{L}= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\beta x_i}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta x_i}y_i} \implies \log(\mathscr{L})= \log\bigg{[}\frac{1}{\beta^n}\bigg{(}\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{x_i}\bigg{)}e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_i}{x_i}} \bigg{]}$$
    $$\text{And Maximizing:} \ -n\log(\beta) +\log\bigg{(} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_i}\bigg{)} -\frac{1}{\beta}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i}{x_i} \implies$$
    $$\frac{\partial \log(\mathscr{L})}{\partial \beta} = -\frac{n}{\beta} + \frac{n}{\beta^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i}{x_i}=0 \implies \hat \beta = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{y_i}{x_i}$$

Comment: It seems fine. What's your question?

Comment: @LandonCarter Simply if my interpretation of the question was correct, it didn't quite make sense if there were $n$ different constants, each altered slightly by $1/x_i$ or something else. - I guess my confusion wasn't really warranted however.

Comment: Let's see. What is your intuition about the mle? Since the distribution is exponential, we should expect some sort of mean to be the mle. Under the mathematical form of your model, you have, $E(Y_i)=\beta x_i$ equivalently, $E(Y_i/x_i)=\beta$.Now you can think of your $Y_i/x_i$ to be scaled exponentials, each with mean $\beta$. What is the mle for $\beta$? Precisely $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{y_i}{x_i}$.

Comment: @LandonCarter great! Thanks for the intuitive explanation.

Comment: Rather than close as "unclear what is being asked", my preference would be that @LandonCarter would post the explanation given in Comment as an Answer.

Comment: OK. I didn't vote to close, by the way.